# Not able to get shape of ndaarray?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

*How to find number of arrays in the following data it is showing type: void*

```
print type(image_mat['polygons'][0][0])
```

> output:

```
print image_mat['polygons'][0][0]
```

> Output:
>   (array([], shape=(1, 0), dtype=float64), array([[814.0257732 ,
>   718.76804124],
>          [810.06701031, 712.17010309],
>          [807.42783505, 705.57216495],
>          [804.78865979, 698.9742268 ],
>          [803.46907216, 693.69587629],
>          [800.82989691, 689.7371134 ],
>          [800.82989691, 685.77835052],
>          [800.82989691, 684.45876289],
>          [800.82989691, 681.81958763],
>          [800.82989691, 679.18041237],
>          [800.82989691, 676.54123711],
>          [800.82989691, 673.90206186],
>          [799.51030928, 672.58247423],
>          [799.51030928, 668.62371134],
>          [799.51030928, 667.30412371],
>          [799.51030928, 665.98453608],
>          [799.51030928, 660.70618557],
>          [799.51030928, 658.06701031],
>          [796.87113402, 655.42783505],
>          [796.87113402, 654.10824742],
>          [794.23195876, 654.10824742],
>          [792.91237113, 651.46907216],
>          [791.59278351, 648.82989691],
>          [790.27319588, 646.19072165],
>          [790.27319588, 643.55154639],
>          [790.27319588, 640.91237113],
>          [791.59278351, 636.95360825],
>          [792.91237113, 636.95360825],
>          [792.91237113, 635.63402062],
>          [794.23195876, 634.31443299],
>          [798.19072165, 627.71649485],
>          [798.19072165, 626.39690722],
>          [799.51030928, 623.75773196],
>          [799.51030928, 622.43814433],
>          [800.82989691, 622.43814433],
>          [803.46907216, 621.1185567 ],
>          [806.10824742, 619.79896907],
>          [807.42783505, 619.79896907],
>          [808.74742268, 619.79896907],
>          [810.06701031, 619.79896907],
>          [811.38659794, 619.79896907],
>          [814.0257732 , 619.79896907],
>          [816.66494845, 619.79896907],
>          [817.98453608, 619.79896907],
>          [819.30412371, 621.1185567 ],
>          [821.94329897, 623.75773196],
>          [823.2628866 , 623.75773196],
>          [827.22164948, 626.39690722],
>          [828.54123711, 626.39690722],
>          [832.5       , 626.39690722],
>          [835.13917526, 626.39690722],
>          [837.77835052, 626.39690722],
>          [839.09793814, 626.39690722],
>          [841.7371134 , 626.39690722],
>          [847.01546392, 626.39690722],
>          [849.65463918, 626.39690722],
>          [850.9742268 , 627.71649485],
>          [853.61340206, 629.03608247],
>          [858.89175258, 630.3556701 ],
>          [864.17010309, 631.67525773],
>          [866.80927835, 631.67525773],
>          [870.76804124, 632.99484536],
>          [873.40721649, 634.31443299],
>          [876.04639175, 636.95360825],
>          [883.96391753, 640.91237113],
>          [885.28350515, 642.23195876],
>          [887.92268041, 643.55154639],
>          [893.20103093, 647.51030928],
>          [895.84020619, 648.82989691],
>          [898.47938144, 651.46907216],
>          [902.43814433, 654.10824742],
>          [905.07731959, 655.42783505],
>          [907.71649485, 658.06701031],
>          [910.3556701 , 660.70618557],
>          [912.99484536, 663.34536082],
>          [922.23195876, 669.94329897],
>          [923.55154639, 672.58247423],
>          [928.82989691, 675.22164948],
>          [932.78865979, 677.86082474],
>          [938.06701031, 684.45876289],
>          [939.38659794, 685.77835052],
>          [943.34536082, 689.7371134 ],
>          [945.98453608, 691.05670103],
>          [949.94329897, 697.65463918],
>          [951.2628866 , 698.9742268 ],
>          [955.22164948, 705.57216495],
>          [957.86082474, 709.53092784],
>          [957.86082474, 713.48969072],
>          [960.5       , 716.12886598],
>          [960.5       , 717.44845361],
>          [961.81958763, 718.76804124]]), array([[730.89175258, 454.85051546],
>          [730.89175258, 460.12886598],
>          [732.21134021, 464.08762887],
>          [734.85051546, 469.36597938],
>          [736.17010309, 470.68556701],
>          [738.80927835, 473.32474227],
>          [740.12886598, 475.96391753],
>          [742.76804124, 478.60309278],
>          [749.36597938, 485.20103093],
>          [753.32474227, 487.84020619],
>          [757.28350515, 489.15979381],
>          [766.52061856, 491.79896907],
>          [770.47938144, 494.43814433],
>          [771.79896907, 495.75773196],
>          [779.71649485, 497.07731959],
>          [788.95360825, 501.03608247],
>          [795.55154639, 503.67525773],
>          [798.19072165, 504.99484536],
>          [803.46907216, 504.99484536],
>          [811.38659794, 508.95360825],
>          [814.0257732 , 510.27319588],
>          [816.66494845, 511.59278351],
>          [820.62371134, 512.91237113],
>          [824.58247423, 516.87113402],
>          [827.22164948, 516.87113402],
>          [832.5       , 519.51030928],
>          [835.13917526, 519.51030928],
>          [839.09793814, 520.82989691],
>          [848.33505155, 520.82989691],
>          [849.65463918, 520.82989691],
>          [852.29381443, 520.82989691],
>          [860.21134021, 519.51030928],
>          [868.12886598, 518.19072165],
>          [876.04639175, 514.23195876],
>          [878.68556701, 514.23195876],
>          [880.00515464, 512.91237113],
>          [881.32474227, 510.27319588],
>          [883.96391753, 507.63402062],
>          [883.96391753, 506.31443299],
>          [885.28350515, 503.67525773],
>          [886.60309278, 501.03608247],
>          [887.92268041, 499.71649485],
>          [890.56185567, 494.43814433],
>          [893.20103093, 491.79896907],
>          [895.84020619, 487.84020619],
>          [898.47938144, 485.20103093],
>          [899.79896907, 483.8814433 ],
>          [901.1185567 , 479.92268041],
>          [903.75773196, 477.28350515],
>          [905.07731959, 473.32474227],
>          [906.39690722, 470.68556701],
>          [909.03608247, 466.72680412],
>          [909.03608247, 465.40721649],
>          [910.3556701 , 461.44845361],
>          [911.67525773, 457.48969072],
>          [911.67525773, 454.85051546],
>          [911.67525773, 452.21134021],
>          [911.67525773, 449.57216495],
>          [909.03608247, 446.93298969],
>          [906.39690722, 442.9742268 ],
>          [905.07731959, 439.01546392],
>          [903.75773196, 437.69587629],
>          [902.43814433, 435.05670103],
>          [899.79896907, 431.09793814],
>          [899.79896907, 429.77835052],
>          [897.15979381, 427.13917526],
>          [895.84020619, 424.5       ],
>          [894.52061856, 421.86082474],
>          [893.20103093, 421.86082474],
>          [893.20103093, 420.54123711],
>          [893.20103093, 419.22164948],
>          [891.8814433 , 417.90206186],
>          [889.24226804, 415.2628866 ],
>          [887.92268041, 415.2628866 ],
>          [885.28350515, 412.62371134],
>          [878.68556701, 409.98453608],
>          [877.36597938, 409.98453608],
>          [873.40721649, 408.66494845],
>          [870.76804124, 408.66494845],
>          [866.80927835, 407.34536082],
>          [860.21134021, 406.0257732 ],
>          [857.57216495, 406.0257732 ],
>          [854.93298969, 406.0257732 ],
>          [850.9742268 , 406.0257732 ],
>          [848.33505155, 406.0257732 ],
>          [844.37628866, 406.0257732 ],
>          [836.45876289, 408.66494845],
>          [835.13917526, 409.98453608],
>          [833.81958763, 409.98453608],
>          [831.18041237, 411.30412371],
>          [829.86082474, 412.62371134],
>          [828.54123711, 413.94329897],
>          [827.22164948, 415.2628866 ],
>          [825.90206186, 416.58247423],
>          [823.2628866 , 417.90206186],
>          [820.62371134, 419.22164948],
>          [819.30412371, 420.54123711],
>          [819.30412371, 421.86082474],
>          [817.98453608, 421.86082474],
>          [817.98453608, 423.18041237],
>          [817.98453608, 424.5       ],
>          [821.94329897, 427.13917526],
>          [824.58247423, 429.77835052],
>          [827.22164948, 431.09793814],
>          [832.5       , 432.41752577],
>          [835.13917526, 432.41752577],
>          [837.77835052, 432.41752577],
>          [840.41752577, 433.7371134 ],
>          [843.05670103, 433.7371134 ],
>          [849.65463918, 436.37628866],
>          [853.61340206, 437.69587629],
>          [854.93298969, 437.69587629],
>          [856.25257732, 439.01546392],
>          [857.57216495, 441.65463918],
>          [858.89175258, 444.29381443],
>          [860.21134021, 445.61340206],
>          [861.53092784, 449.57216495],
>          [861.53092784, 450.89175258],
>          [861.53092784, 452.21134021],
>          [861.53092784, 453.53092784],
>          [861.53092784, 454.85051546],
>          [860.21134021, 454.85051546],
>          [856.25257732, 457.48969072],
>          [853.61340206, 457.48969072],
>          [852.29381443, 457.48969072],
>          [848.33505155, 458.80927835],
>          [843.05670103, 458.80927835],
>          [839.09793814, 458.80927835],
>          [832.5       , 460.12886598],
>          [820.62371134, 460.12886598],
>          [815.34536082, 460.12886598],
>          [808.74742268, 460.12886598],
>          [803.46907216, 460.12886598],
>          [799.51030928, 458.80927835],
>          [798.19072165, 458.80927835],
>          [794.23195876, 458.80927835],
>          [791.59278351, 457.48969072],
>          [786.31443299, 457.48969072],
>          [784.99484536, 457.48969072],
>          [781.03608247, 456.17010309],
>          [774.43814433, 454.85051546],
>          [771.79896907, 454.85051546],
>          [770.47938144, 454.85051546],
>          [769.15979381, 453.53092784],
>          [766.52061856, 453.53092784],
>          [765.20103093, 452.21134021],
>          [759.92268041, 449.57216495],
>          [758.60309278, 449.57216495],
>          [757.28350515, 449.57216495]]), array([[602.89175258, 391.51030928],
>          [597.61340206, 394.14948454],
>          [594.9742268 , 398.10824742],
>          [592.33505155, 404.70618557],
>          [592.33505155, 409.98453608],
>          [591.01546392, 413.94329897],
>          [591.01546392, 417.90206186],
>          [591.01546392, 421.86082474],
>          [591.01546392, 428.45876289],
>          [593.65463918, 439.01546392],
>          [594.9742268 , 442.9742268 ],
>          [594.9742268 , 445.61340206],
>          [598.93298969, 450.89175258],
>          [601.57216495, 454.85051546],
>          [601.57216495, 457.48969072],
>          [605.53092784, 462.76804124],
>          [608.17010309, 468.04639175],
>          [610.80927835, 470.68556701],
>          [614.76804124, 475.96391753],
>          [616.08762887, 477.28350515],
>          [617.40721649, 479.92268041],
>          [620.04639175, 482.56185567],
>          [621.36597938, 485.20103093],
>          [622.68556701, 487.84020619],
>          [624.00515464, 489.15979381],
>          [629.28350515, 493.1185567 ],
>          [630.60309278, 493.1185567 ],
>          [631.92268041, 493.1185567 ],
>          [641.15979381, 494.43814433],
>          [643.79896907, 494.43814433],
>          [649.07731959, 495.75773196],
>          [654.3556701 , 495.75773196],
>          [660.95360825, 495.75773196],
>          [663.59278351, 495.75773196],
>          [666.23195876, 495.75773196],
>          [675.46907216, 495.75773196],
>          [678.10824742, 495.75773196],
>          [679.42783505, 495.75773196],
>          [680.74742268, 495.75773196],
>          [682.06701031, 495.75773196],
>          [683.38659794, 495.75773196],
>          [686.0257732 , 495.75773196],
>          [687.34536082, 494.43814433],
>          [688.66494845, 493.1185567 ],
>          [691.30412371, 491.79896907],
>          [696.58247423, 489.15979381],
>          [699.22164948, 487.84020619],
>          [704.5       , 482.56185567],
>          [707.13917526, 478.60309278],
>          [708.45876289, 475.96391753],
>          [711.09793814, 472.00515464],
>          [712.41752577, 466.72680412],
>          [713.7371134 , 464.08762887],
>          [716.37628866, 458.80927835],
>          [717.69587629, 454.85051546],
>          [717.69587629, 453.53092784],
>          [717.69587629, 450.89175258],
>          [717.69587629, 449.57216495],
>          [716.37628866, 448.25257732],
>          [712.41752577, 446.93298969],
>          [709.77835052, 442.9742268 ],
>          [704.5       , 439.01546392],
>          [703.18041237, 437.69587629],
>          [700.54123711, 435.05670103],
>          [699.22164948, 433.7371134 ],
>          [697.90206186, 432.41752577],
>          [696.58247423, 431.09793814],
>          [695.2628866 , 431.09793814],
>          [695.2628866 , 428.45876289],
>          [696.58247423, 427.13917526],
>          [697.90206186, 425.81958763],
>          [700.54123711, 425.81958763],
>          [701.86082474, 425.81958763],
>          [703.18041237, 425.81958763],
>          [705.81958763, 424.5       ],
>          [705.81958763, 423.18041237],
>          [708.45876289, 423.18041237],
>          [711.09793814, 421.86082474],
>          [712.41752577, 420.54123711],
>          [713.7371134 , 417.90206186],
>          [715.05670103, 416.58247423],
>          [715.05670103, 413.94329897],
>          [716.37628866, 412.62371134],
>          [716.37628866, 408.66494845],
>          [716.37628866, 406.0257732 ],
>          [713.7371134 , 400.74742268],
>          [713.7371134 , 399.42783505],
>          [709.77835052, 395.46907216],
>          [707.13917526, 390.19072165],
>          [705.81958763, 388.87113402],
>          [701.86082474, 384.91237113],
>          [700.54123711, 383.59278351],
>          [695.2628866 , 382.27319588],
>          [684.70618557, 378.31443299],
>          [683.38659794, 376.99484536],
>          [678.10824742, 376.99484536],
>          [676.78865979, 376.99484536],
>          [672.82989691, 375.67525773],
>          [668.87113402, 375.67525773],
>          [667.55154639, 375.67525773],
>          [666.23195876, 375.67525773],
>          [662.27319588, 375.67525773],
>          [656.99484536, 375.67525773],
>          [653.03608247, 375.67525773],
>          [651.71649485, 375.67525773],
>          [650.39690722, 375.67525773]]))

```
print image_mat['polygons'][0][0].shape
```

> output:
>   ()

Comment: Can you provide some context on what image_mat is? and what is in image_mat[0][0]?

Comment: image_mat is a matfile,image_mat[0][i][j][k] i represents no of hands j represents no of (x,y) coordinate list of each hand k represents x or y value of the coordinate

Comment: i am not able to find no of hands in the matfile which needs image_mat[0][0].shape?

Comment: Output of print type(image_mat['polygons'][0][0]) is <type 'numpy.void'>

Comment: @chrisz i tried converting ino numpy array and then find shape it still gives Output: ()

Answer (score 0):

```
len(image_mat['polygons'][0][0])
```

Comment: yes you are correct about that but it shape (1,0) while in the above output i presented in question i can see 3 arrays

Comment: `print image_mat['polygons'][0][0][1].shape` gives output:(1,0) but i can see 3 arrays in the output provided in thee question

Comment: Ah, I didn't see those arrays buried in there. There are four arrays actually unless you don't count the first empty one. Editing my answer now.

Comment: I see you just needed the number of arrays in the tuple. I know you have already completed this, but this can be simplified to `len(image_mat['polygons'][0][0])`

Answer (score 0):

```
print image_mat['polygons'][0][0].shape
output: ()
```

`()` is a valid shape - for a 0-d array.

Look at

```
image_mat['polygons'][0][0].item()
```

or

```
image_mat['polygons'][0][0][()]
```

to work your way down another layer.

My guess is that you have loaded a complex MATLAB structure (via `loadmat`).  MATLAB matrices are returned as nd numeric arrays, but cells are 2d object dtype arrays, and structs may be 0-d object arrays.  Somethings might also be structured arrays (with field names). You just have to patiently work your way through the structure.

Do a search on `loadmat`, [scipy], [matlab] to see other SO questions about these structures.